# MySQL Stored Procedure for splitting a String value and comparing it against the multiple columns present in a table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a `stored procedure` in `MySQL` which take a `String` value as input parameter, I have to `Split` that `String` value based on `/` and `, (Comma)` and have to compare the values in a table i.e. `table1` with its multiple columns.

the table structure of `table1` is as follows

```
id  name    type    max1    min1    max2    min2    max3    min3    max4    min4    max5    min5    max6    min6    max7    min7    max8    min8    max9    min9    max10   min10
1   AL123   tools   123     123                                                                                                                                                 
2   AL124   tools                   123     123                                                                                                                                 
3   AL131   tools                                                                                   123     123                                                                 
4   AL411   tools                                                                                                                                                   123     123 
5   AL519   tools                                   415     311
```

The `table1`holds the date in the above format and the `Stored Procedure` i had written is as below shown

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `USPCompare`
( 
IN StringValue LONGTEXT,
    IN DelimiterChar  VARCHAR(1),
    OUT m1 varchar(200),
    OUT m2 varchar(200),
    OUT m3 varchar(200),
    OUT m4 varchar(200),
    OUT m5 varchar(200),
    OUT m6 varchar(200),
    OUT m7 varchar(200),
    OUT m8 varchar(200),
    OUT m9 varchar(200),
    OUT m10 varchar(200)
)
BEGIN
    # BEGIN split statements ids
         DECLARE current_pos INT DEFAULT 1;
     DECLARE delim CHAR DEFAULT '/';
     DECLARE delim1 CHAR DEFAULT ',';
     DECLARE current CHAR DEFAULT '';
     DECLARE current_id VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '';
     DECLARE statement_ids VARCHAR(5000) DEFAULT '';  
         DECLARE cursor_VAL1 VARCHAR(100);
         DECLARE cursor_VAL2 VARCHAR(100);
         DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
         DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(id,'/',1) AS major,SUBSTRING(id,LOCATE('/',id)+1, LENGTH(id) ) AS minor FROM ids;
         DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

 SET statement_ids=StringValue;

     DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS ids;
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ids (`id` VARCHAR(100));

 split_ids: LOOP
  SET current = MID(statement_ids, current_pos, 1);
  IF (current_pos = LENGTH(statement_ids)) THEN
            IF current != delim THEN 
                    SET current_id = CONCAT(current_id,current); 
            END IF;
                    INSERT INTO ids(id) VALUES (current_id);
                    LEAVE split_ids;
  END IF;
  IF current = delim1 THEN
                    INSERT INTO ids(id) VALUES (current_id);
                    SET current_id = '';
  ELSE
                    SET current_id = CONCAT(current_id,current);
  END IF;
  SET current_pos = current_pos+1;
        END LOOP split_ids;
        # END split statement ids

        # to check ids are correct
        SELECT * FROM ids;

        SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(id,'/',1) AS major ,SUBSTRING(id,LOCATE('/',id)+1, LENGTH(id) ) AS minor FROM ids ;

        OPEN cursor_i;
            read_loop: LOOP
                FETCH cursor_i INTO cursor_VAL1, cursor_VAL2;
                SELECT  table1.*,  inventory.id,
                                 inventory.mls_id,
                                 itm.parent_id,
                                 itm.item_type,
                                 itm.item_name,
                                 itm.item_cat
                            FROM
                                 inventory
                            LEFT JOIN  itm ON  inventory.id =  itm.parent_id
                            LEFT JOIN  table1 ON  inventory.mls_id =  table1.mls_name
                            WHERE
                                (
                                    (
                                         table1.max1 = cursor_VAL1
                                        AND  table1.min1 = cursor_VAL2
                                    )
                                    OR (
                                         table1.max2 = cursor_VAL1
                                        AND  table1.min2 = cursor_VAL2
                                    )
                                    OR (
                                         table1.max3 = cursor_VAL1
                                        AND  table1.min3 = cursor_VAL2
                                    )
                                    OR (
                                         table1.max4 = cursor_VAL1
                                        AND  table1.min4 = cursor_VAL2
                                    )
                                    OR (
                                         table1.max5 = cursor_VAL1
                                        AND  table1.min5 = cursor_VAL2
                                    )
                                    OR (
                                         table1.max6 = cursor_VAL1
                                        AND  table1.min6 = cursor_VAL2
                                    )
                                    OR (
                                         table1.max7 = cursor_VAL1
                                        AND  table1.min7 = cursor_VAL2
                                    )
                                    OR (
                                         table1.max8 = cursor_VAL1
                                        AND  table1.min8 = cursor_VAL2
                                    )
                                    OR (
                                         table1.max9 = cursor_VAL1
                                        AND  table1.min9 = cursor_VAL2
                                    )
                                    OR (
                                         table1.max10 = cursor_VAL1
                                        AND  table1.min10 = cursor_VAL2
                                    )
                                )
                            GROUP BY
                                 itm.parent_id;
                IF done THEN
                    LEAVE read_loop;
                END IF;

            END LOOP;
            CLOSE cursor_i;

END
```

Also to inform i had used a cursor in same procedure to fetch the splited data from temporary table and compare it with the data in table `table1`.

Now when i provide the input parameter as follows
`call USPCompare("123/123, 415/311""/",@m1,@m2,@m3,@m4,@m5,@m6,@m7,@m8,@m9,@m10);` in this format i get the result in different result set but i want a table which consist all the result set in one output table.

Comment: Having numbered columns that all contain the same "type" of data is usually a sign of a broken data model. Usually, what you ought to have is a narrower table with more rows; just one pair of min and max columns - and an extra column to contain the data,  numbers between 1 and 10, which is currently embedded in the column *names* where it's far more difficult to write sensible queries with.

Comment: since this is what i am using now, i know this is a bad concept but i am stuck to this only any approach you have in mind can suggest me in achieving what i desire the output to be